# How do I get matplotlib animation title to update from a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a matplotlib animation but the title will not change.

I have tried both set_title and set_text but it will only show the last title in the list.

```
%matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

plt.rcdefaults()
x=range(0,3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
people = ['Dan', 'Jimmy','']
titleList=['Basketball','Hockey','Baseball']
frame=[[4,9,0],[2,6,0],[2,8,0]]
barcollection = plt.barh(x,frame[0])
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_title("Project")
ax.set_xlabel("Knowledge Level")
title = plt.text(0.5,0.95, "Basketball", bbox={'facecolor':'r', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},
                transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(people)),people)

def animate(i):
    while i<2:
        y=frame[i+1]
        print(y)
        for i, b in enumerate(barcollection):
            title.set_text(str(titleList[i]))
            b.set_width(y[i])

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,repeat=False,blit=False,frames=3,
                             interval=2000)

anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=.2))

plt.show()
```

Comment: You use `i` both as a parameter for `animate(i)` and in the for loop. Please seperate this!

Comment: You are absolutely right. My code was collected from many different sources and this is where the mistake came from. Good catch and thank you for the answer below!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the while loop and moved the set_text out of the loop. It needs to be dependant of i, not of j:

```
%matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

plt.rcdefaults()
x=range(0,3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
people = ['Dan', 'Jimmy','']
titleList=['Basketball','Hockey','Baseball']
frame=[[4,9,0],[2,6,0],[2,8,0]]
barcollection = plt.barh(x,frame[0])
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_title("Project")
ax.set_xlabel("Knowledge Level")
title = plt.text(0.5,0.95, "Basketball", bbox={'facecolor':'r', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5},
                transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(people)),people)


def animate(i):
    y=frame[i]
    print(y)
    title.set_text(str(titleList[i]))
    for j, b in enumerate(barcollection):
        b.set_width(y[j])

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,repeat=False,blit=False,frames=3,
                             interval=2000)

anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=.2))

plt.show()
```